# How to detect path overlapping in Raphael.js

Tags: graph

I'm using the dracula js from http://www.graphdracula.net/ for drawing diagrams.

This uses raphael.js internally for drawing the paths to the edges.

My issue is that I am drawing an edge from `A-->B` and from `B-->A` but during rendering the lines get overlapped and cannot identify the paths.

How do I draw different lines from source to target from each other without overlapping?